# Key listener in Service

Tags: android, service, background, volume, keylistener

I am new to android and I extensively searched for this. Any help would be much appreciated:)
I have a requirement for an application which does the following:

An application that runs in the background as a service that listens to the volume key(UP/Down). On this event an activity will be displayed in foreground.

[I am able to do this from an Activity, however the activity has to be at the foreground and only after I press the volume button I get a toast.]

Please HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BroadcastReceiver that listens to `android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON` and register an intent filter to listen to it:

```
<receiver android:name=".RemoteControlReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

then in your receiver you handle the change:

```
public class RemoteControlReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN == event.getKeyCode()) {
                // Handle key press.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html for more information (this code was taken from there)

*Edit: fixed KeyEvent key code constant*